# docker compose jest integration tests cannot make intra-container http requests RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: http, docker, docker-compose, axios, jestjs

I have a docker compose stack with a few containers. The two in question are an extended `python:3-onbuild` container (see base image [here](https://github.com/hallooinc/python3-onbuild-nginx-node/blob/master/Dockerfile)) with a falcon webserver running and a basic `node:8.11-alpine` container that is attempting to make post requests to the python webserver. The python webserver is making database calls to a `postgres:alpine` container. This is a simplified version of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yml
version: '3.6'

services:
  app: # python:3-onbuild
    ports:
      - 5000
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: infra/docker/app.Dockerfile

  lambda: # node:8.11-alpine
    ports:
      - 10000
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: infra/docker/lambda.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app

   db: # postgres:alpine
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      build:
        context: ../../
        dockerfile: infra/docker/db.Dockerfile
```

I have a suite of integration tests I'm trying to pass. When I run the tests with an endpoint in the outside world (https python server running the same code as the `app` service) all of the tests pass. The problem arises when I try to make these requests against the `app` service from within my `docker-compose` stack, specifically from the `lambda` service to the `app` service.

I don't think it is a timing issue. In the `beforeAll` function of my jest suite, I poll the python server for 100 seconds, once every 10 seconds like this:

In my jest test

```ts
beforeAll(async () => {
    const endpointUrl = getEndpointUrl();
    const status = await checkStatus(endpointUrl, 10);

    // NOTE: never reaches this line, starts tests before 5-minute timeout
    console.log(`[integration.test]: status = ${status}`);
}, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 5-minute timeout for async function
```

Where `checkStatus()` is defined

```ts
/**
 * Checks the status of the backend every 10 seconds, n times
 * @param {string} endpointUrl 
 * @param {number} n 
 */
export function checkStatus(endpointUrl: string, n: number): Promise<string> {
    console.log(`[lib][checkStatus]: before timeout date = ${Date()}`);
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        checkStatusHelper(endpointUrl, n, resolve, reject);
    });
}

function checkStatusHelper(endpointUrl, n, resolve, reject): void {
    if (n === 0) reject();
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`[lib][checkStatus]: after timeout date ${n} = ${Date()}`);
        rp.get(`${endpointUrl}/status`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(`[lib][checkStatus]: after request date = ${Date()}`);
                console.log(`[lib][checkStatus]: res = ${res}`);
                resolve('success');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`[lib][checkStatus]: err = ${err}`);
                checkStatusHelper(endpointUrl, n - 1, resolve, reject);
            });
    }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

I get output like the following (with `request-promise-native`):

```bash
  console.log src/lib.ts:30
    [lib][checkStatus]: before timeout date = Fri May 11 2018 01:54:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)

  console.log src/lib.ts:39
    [lib][checkStatus]: after timeout date 10 = Fri May 11 2018 01:54:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)

  console.log src/lib.ts:47
    [lib][checkStatus]: err = RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app app:5000

  console.log src/lib.ts:39
    [lib][checkStatus]: after timeout date 9 = Fri May 11 2018 01:54:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)

  console.log src/lib.ts:47
    [lib][checkStatus]: err = RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app app:5000

# etc ...
```

And similar output with `axios` instead of `request-promise-native`

```
  console.log src/lib.ts:30
    [lib][checkStatus]: before timeout date = Fri May 11 2018 01:56:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)

  console.log src/lib.ts:39
    [lib][checkStatus]: after timeout date 10 = Fri May 11 2018 01:57:07 GMT+0000 (UTC)

  console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app app:5000
        at Object.dispatchError (/Halloo/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (/Halloo/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Request.onRequestError (/Halloo/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) undefined

  console.log src/lib.ts:47
    [lib][checkStatus]: err = Error: Network Error

  console.log src/lib.ts:39
    [lib][checkStatus]: after timeout date 9 = Fri May 11 2018 01:57:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)

  console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND app app:5000
        at Object.dispatchError (/Halloo/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at Request.client.on.err (/Halloo/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Request.onRequestError (/Halloo/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) undefined

  console.log src/lib.ts:47
    [lib][checkStatus]: err = Error: Network Error

# etc ...
```

I also don't think it is not a networking issue. If I comment out my test step and let the `lambda` service spin up normally, I can ssh into the lambda container and test the connection using `axios` or `request-promise-native`. This `/status` endpoint simply returns the all the table names in my database to ensure the database container is also running properly. This works almost instantly, and far before 100 seconds

```bash
$ node
> const axios = require('axios')
undefined
> axios.get('http://app:5000/status').then(res => console.log(res.data));
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> [ [ 'table0' ],
    [ 'table1' ],
    [ 'table2' ],
    [ 'table3' ],
    [ 'table4' ],
    [ 'table5' ] ]
```

I thought maybe I can't use jest for these purposes, but I feel like I can because everything works flawlessly when I change the url to my production https endpoint running in aws and comment out the `beforeAll()` step in my jest suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with my jest configuration

> The default environment in Jest is a browser-like environment through jsdom. If you are building a node service, you can use the node option to use a node-like environment instead.

To fix this I had to add this in my jest.config.js file:

```
{
  // ...
  testEnvironment: 'node'
  // ...
}
```

Source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1418